# Best way to communicate with an API server

Tags: angularjs, node.js, api

I have an angular app on a node js server. On another machine, I have an API server. My dilemma is how to communicate with the API server. The first approach is to send all my AJAX calls directly to the API server. The downside of this approach that the client will see how I send the requests to the API, including the secret key I send in the headers. This means I will have to work harder to secure my API. The other approach is to send my requests to my node js server, and then forward them to the API server. The downside of this approach, however, is increased latency, since it will require two serial HTTP requests. I would love to hear from you what you think is the best way to handle this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First approach, and you "have to work harder to secure your API". I recommend JWT autthorization.

Answer (score 0):

The most popular and reliable solution for this widely followed architecture style (Front End App to Backend API Server) is OAuth.

OAuth is very easy to setup and use with Angular Js.
As far as AJAX calls are concerned, if your application entails this behavior make sure your API is enable with CORS capability.